# what the difference between handle and create?

Tags: project-reactor

##### Article background

i am trying to figure out that the difference between`handle`and `create`;
i had  refer to  the [reactor offical documents](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html#_handle) , but the  sample which offical  provided , could not point me to understand  the diff  with  handle and create

- The `handle` sample

```
Flux<String> alphabet = Flux.just(-1, 30, 13, 9, 20)
    .handle((i, sink) -> {
        String letter = alphabet(i); 
        if (letter != null) 
            sink.next(letter); 
    });

alphabet.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

- The `create` sample

```
Flux<String> bridge = Flux.create(sink -> {
    myEventProcessor.register( 
      new MyEventListener<String>() { 

        public void onDataChunk(List<String> chunk) {
          for(String s : chunk) {
            sink.next(s); 
          }
        }

        public void processComplete() {
            sink.complete(); 
        }
    });
});
```

both sample above  are from [reactor offical documents](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html#_handle) , obviously , both of them have the operation  `sink` that used to  generate one by one (not sure  , also have confusion in it ) , so the `handle` is not necessary when we need to generate datas , just use `create`  instead of ``handle``` ?;

##### Main Question

Finally  ， i have collect the question in summary

- Could use the `create` instead of `handle` every time?
  is there some best practice or  useage in both of the operation above?
- Is it  generate data step-by-step with the operation `sink`?
  if i have some IO operate in code before `sink.nest()` , it will block util the IO complate? so that  is it will block for  thw dowstream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although these samples produce similar results `Flux.create` has a different purpose that `handle`.

**`Flux.create`** could be used to create a `Flux` by emitting multiple elements.

```
@Test
void fluxCreateRange() {
    Flux<Integer> range = Flux.create(emitter -> {
        FluxSink<Integer> sink = emitter.next(0);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            sink.next(i);
        }

        sink.complete();
    });

    StepVerifier.create(range)
            .expectNext(0, 1, 2, 3)
            .verifyComplete();
}
```

The above code is the same as `Flux.range(0, 3)`;

**`handle`** is used to process data as a part of the flow. The closest analog of the `handle` is a `map`. You could think about it as a combination of the `map` & `filter`. In contrast to `flatMap` both `handle` and `map` are synchronous function.

`map` - transforms the emitted item by applying a synchronous function. It provides 1:1 mapping and **every** item should be mapped. The only way to skip item is to throw exception and then immediately handle the error signal using `onErrorResume`.

`handle` - is more flexible and provides 0 or 1 mapping. It's possible to skip items by not emitting signal using `sink.next()`.

In your case there is no reason to wrap user into `Mono` and use `flatMap`. Use `map` because mapping is 1:1.

Comment: Thanks for you help , I think i got the  point .